# Problems minifying/aggregating CSS/JS files with Symfony 2.5 and UglifyCSS/JS

Tags: php, node.js, symfony, uglifyjs2, uglifycss

I have followed [these instructions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/uglifyjs.html) in order to enable both UglifyJs2 and UglifyCss on my development environment (to start with... can't risk taking down the production server with this problem!)

Under my `config_dev.yml` I have configured the following (I've started with just the `bin` parameters but added extra configurations just in case something else was causing a problem.)

```
assetic:
    use_controller: %use_assetic_controller%
    filters:
        uglifycss:
            bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/.bin/uglifycss"
            node: /usr/local/bin/node
            apply_to: '\.css$'
        uglifyjs2:
            bin: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/node_modules/.bin/uglifyjs"
            node: /usr/local/bin/node
            apply_to: '\.js$'
```

and in my `base.html.twig` file:

```
  {% javascripts  'bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js'
                  'bundles/legalcheck/js/angular.min.js'
                  'bundles/legalcheck/js/plugins/*'
                  'bundles/legalcheck/js/app.js'
                  'bundles/legalcheck/js/controllers/*'
                  filter='uglifyjs2'
                %}
      <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
  {% endjavascripts %}
```

and

```
  {% stylesheets 'bundles/legalcheck/css/*' filter='cssrewrite' filter='uglifycss' %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
  {% endstylesheets %}
```

When I run `php app/console assetic:dump --env=prod --verbose`, all files are generated with no errors. They're even minified at this point!

However, when I load the app in the browser, **all** of the CSS and JS assets return a 500 error.

[image: 500 Errors]

[Here's what each Javascript file returns](http://pastebin.com/0wqv5KES), along with [what each CSS file returns](http://pastebin.com/hBKT2CuM). I am getting a signal "5" error from what seems like both UglifyJS and/or UglifyCSS, or Node itself. I suspect the wrong thing is being sent somewhere.

Any ideas? I'm running a local MAMP server to achieve a development environment. Also note I've taken the space out of "Git Repos" in my path to avoid obvious problems like path issues as a troubleshooting step.

## Update

I tried running the same settings in `config_dev.yml` into my `config_prod.yml` and found that everything works perfectly on the production side. It seems that trying to load the minified assets through `app_dev.php` causes problems... but I still don't know what! It would be nice if minification could be tested through the dev environment, which is why I'm leaving the question open for both this problem and to encourage dialogue for a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**assetic's debug mode :)**

you're dumping the files with `--prod` ( which has **debug mode** disabled by default) ...

... and try to access them in the `dev` environment afterwards.

If debug mode is *enabled* asset collections will be split into **multiple** files that look like this:

```
<hash>_partX_<filename>.js
```

This is what chrome devtools shows you and a problem while dumping on-the-fly leads to the `500` errors.

You didn't dump these files for debugging with the command you invoked and (as long as you don't have `use_controller: true`) they won't be dumped on the fly either.

If you have `use_controller: true` ... any non-zero exit code of a filter-run will result in a `500` error. That's what you experience.

---

**solution:**

Either disable `debug` mode for a single asset collection like this ...

```
{% javascripts  '...'
    filter='uglifyjs2'
    debug=false
 %}
```

... or add ...

```
assetic:
  debug: false
```

to your **config_dev.yml** to resolve the issue.

Finally dump your assets with `app/console assetic:dump` and the correct environment flag.

Comment: Oops, my question didn't mention that I also ran `php app/console assetic:dump` on its own (I don't know why I haven't mentioned that...), and I still had the problems. However I didn't try your solution with debug mode in the asset collection. Instead of adding `debug=false`, I just went with `filter='?uglifyjs2'` to turn off Uglify in the dev environments.